# Stationary distribution for Kolmogorov Forward Equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Given $X_t$ which satisfies the following SDE,

$$
dX_t = f'(X_t)dt + \sigma dW_t
$$

where f is an infinitely differentiable function, and $f'$ above is the first derivative of $f$.

We know that the Kolmogorov Forward Equation is,

$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial{(pf')}}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial^2 x} = 0
$$

How do i show that the $Ae^{2f(x)/\sigma^2}$ is a solution for the stationary distribution?

What is did was the following,

The stationary distribution is given by the solution to,

$$
\frac{\partial{(Pf')}}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial^2 x} = 0
$$

So we substitute $Ae^{2f(x)/\sigma^2}$ into the above equation to get,

$$
\begin{align}
&f''(x)Ae^{2f(x)/\sigma^2} + 2f'(x)^2/\sigma^2 Ae^{2f(x)/\sigma^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\left( 4f'(x)^2/\sigma^4 \right)Ae^{2f(x)/\sigma^2}\\
&=f''(x)Ae^{2f(x)/\sigma^2}
\end{align}
$$

which doesn't seem to solve the equation correctly.

Did I make some silly mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d P}{d x} = \frac{2f'(x)}{\sigma^2}P$$
$$\frac{d^2 P}{d x^2} = \frac{2f''(x)}{\sigma^2}P + \frac{2f'(x)}{\sigma^2}P' = \frac{2f''(x)}{\sigma^2}P + \frac{4(f'(x))^2}{\sigma^4}P$$

It appears that you included the second term in the above derivation but forgot the first term.  Adding it in gives you zero.

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I made such a silly mistake! I think one shouldn't try to do math when one is too tired!